# Disable initial load of transform in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate a divs height using :target and transform: scaleY(1).

So the short version is:

```
#divID { 
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
#divID:target { 
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

It is working. But it is initially shrinking the div once on page load. So my question ist how do I get rid of that initial load of the transform on page load?

PS: I want to use CSS/HTML only. Thanks.

EDIT: I don't know if it matters but the position of the divID is fixed to bottom.

```css
#divID { 
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
 -o-transform: scaleY(0);
 -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
 transform: scaleY(0);

 -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
 -o-transform-origin: bottom;
 -ms-transform-origin: bottom;
 transform-origin: bottom;

 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s ease;
 transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
#divID:target { 
 -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
 -o-transform: scaleY(1);
 -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
 transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
  <p> Some Text </p>
</div>

<a href="#divID"><div id="trigger">Trigger</div></a>
<a href="#ddisable"><div>Close</div></a>
```

Comment: When do you want the css to fire?

Comment: I use a div to trigger the :target on #divID. It is working except the initial load.

Comment: I think url of the page you are working is something like this: `http://www.example.com/file.htm#divID` is it true? if yes thats the problem.

Comment: No I had this in mind. Still occurs when deleting the #divID from the url.

Comment: Is your issue that it appears not scaled on page load and the `scaleY(0)` transform animation then occurs?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure the `#divID` is hidden on pageload, you can make it transparent with the `opacity` property or similar. You can then immediately make it visible when scaling back up. This will prevent your initial 0.3s animation of `#divID` "closing" from showing to the end user.

```
#divID { 
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: bottom;    
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
#divID:target { 
    transform: scaleY(1);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: It does the trick! I tried this with display none/block but it didn't work. Thanks a lot!